ECDSA certificates not impacted by Let’s Encrypt certificate chain change?
We received an email from Cloudflare about the upcoming Let’s Encrypt certificate chain change.
At some point, it states that "Additionally, this change only impacts RSA certificates. It does not impact ECDSA certificates issued through Let’s Encrypt. ECDSA certificates will maintain the same level of compatibility that they have today. "
We checked the certificate used when browsing to our website, and the signature algorithm is “X9.62 ECDSA Signature with SHA-384”.
Does that mean that we are not affected by the change in any possible way?
Or is it that since we are using Universal SSL, Cloudflare might change the certificate at any moment, and might issue an RSA one in replacement?
Thanks in advance for the help!
